# Creep function of the standard linear solid

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to plot the creep function of the standard linear solid model. Here is the picture:
[image: Creep Function of SLS] obtained from https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/materials-science/viscoelasticity

but my graph is very different, despite following the equations in the picture. Can anyone help me figure out where I am going wrong in my code?

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t0 = 15
t = np.linspace(t0, 100, 100)
t1 = 85
E1 = 10
E2 = 8
eta = 4
sigma = 20
eps0 = 10
tau = eta / E1 + eta/E2

# creep function
creep = np.zeros(len(t))
for i in range(len(t)):
    if t[i] < t0:
        creep[i] = sigma / (E1 + E2)
    elif t0 < t[i] < t1:
        creep[i] = (eps0 - sigma / (E1 + E2)) * (1 - np.exp(-(t[i] - t0) / tau))
    elif t[i] == t1:
        creep[i] = sigma/(E1+E2)
    elif t[i] > t1:
        creep[i] = (eps0 - sigma / (E1 + E2)) * np.exp(-(t1 - t[i]) / tau)

# plot graph
plt.plot(t, creep)
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Creep')
plt.title('Creep Function of Standard Linear Solid Model')
plt.show()
```

I've tried extensively to change the graph and have even tried to use different formulas, but I just can't get the shape to match up.

Comment: Your code looks different from the formulas in the image. Could you carefully check it? E.g. `(eps0 - sigma / (E1 + E2))` might be `(sigma / E1) * (1 - E2 / (E1 + E2))`, if I understand correctly.

Comment: (1) Your numbers are inconsistent with the sigma plot found at the link, which says that `sigma_0 = epsilon_0*(E1+E2)`. (2) The equations do not match the plot. To get that initial profile, you need a function like `1-exp(-x)`, but the equations in the image are just exponential decay (which would define the right region).

Comment: I've made a Desmos plot that seems to be more along the lines of what the plot should look like. For the first portion of the plot, I brought the exponential inside to multiply the second term. Link: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/y9s3ahwjvf

Answer (score 0):

As in the comments: your math doesn't match the equations, and the equations don't match the plot. An educated guess at which parts are right and which parts are wrong produces

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t0 = 15
t1 = 85
E1 = 10
E2 = 8
eta = 4
sigma0 = 20
eps0 = sigma0/E1
tau = eta*(1/E1 + 1/E2)

ta = np.linspace(0, t0, 3)
tb = np.linspace(t0, t1, 200)
tc = np.linspace(t1, 100, 200)

epsa = np.zeros_like(ta)
epsb = sigma0*(1/(E1 + E2) + (1/E1 - 1/(E1 + E2)) * (1 - np.exp(-(tb - t0)/tau)))
epsc = (eps0 - sigma0/(E1 + E2)) * np.exp(-(tc - t1)/tau)

plt.plot(
    np.concatenate((ta, tb, tc)),
    np.concatenate((epsa, epsb, epsc)),
)
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Creep')
plt.title('Creep Function of Standard Linear Solid Model')
plt.show()
```

[image: creep]

But you really do need to find a more authoritative source.